# Where download examples of itextsharp?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

Where I can download C# examples for usage itextsharp? Link http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/tutorial/signatures/ is broken (the most interesting for me is signatures).

All links from http://support.itextpdf.com/node/178 does not work.

Comment: use google =)) https://www.google.com/webhp?client=opera&sourceid=opera#newwindow=1&q=itextsharp

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very helpful.

Comment: The original C# examples are hosted on Sourceforge. Unfortunately, Sourceforge suffered from a major outage a couple of weeks ago and they have not fully restored every service. This means that the examples can't be reached for the moment. This is very annoying. We are now working on a new web site of our own where we could host the examples so that we no longer depend on Sourceforge. That will take some time...

Comment: Their website has some examples / documentation: http://developers.itextpdf.com/

Comment: iTextSharp is now called "iText 7 for .NET"or "itext7-dotnet" on github:  [link](https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet). It's recommended to add itext7 with Nuget to your solution.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of resources available out there. Just use google. However I am referring a couple of tutorials that will serve as good example

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/f2e803/basic-pdf-creation-using-itextsharp-part-i/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686994/Create-Read-Advance-PDF-Report-using-iTextSharp-in

Comment: I'm try to find original examples and tutorials for signing pdf's. But all links are on sf.net and broken...

Comment: I am afraid no one can help you if there is a broken link out there on the internet. May be try to contact itextsharp's support teaam they may be help you with it

Comment: Contacts page contains advice to post questions on stackoverflow. Let's hope that Bruno Lowagie will see this page. :)

Answer (score 3):

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686994/Create-Read-Advance-PDF-Report-using-iTextSharp-in

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/277065/Creating-PDF-documents-with-iTextSharp

All the tutorials of iTextSharp like use : kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/